# how to set which vector roll first in `expand.grid`?

Tags: r

In R, `expand.grid` list the combination of enrolled vectors. it rolls the first vector first, please advise how to make the later vector to roll first?
my lengthy way is `data.table(expand.grid(1:3,"-",1:2))[,.(str_c(Var3, Var2, Var1))]`

```
expand.grid(1:3,1:2)
    Var1 Var2 Var3
# 1    1    -    1
# 2    2    -    1
# 3    3    -    1
# 4    1    -    2
# 5    2    -    2
# 6    3    -    2

#expected result
# 1    1    -    1
# 2    1    -    2
# 3    1    -    3
# 4    2    -    1
# 5    2    -    2
# 6    2    -    3
```

Comment: you can `order` by whichever column you want

Comment: Reorder the columns when you're done. `rev(expand.grid(1:3, 1:2))`

Comment: By the way, if you're after a "data.table" in the end, you can also use `CJ`, like this: `library(data.table); CJ(1:2, 1:3)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tidyr::crossing` which is similar to `expand.grid` does this by default

```
tidyr::crossing(a = 1:2, b = 1:3)

#      a     b
#   <int> <int>
#1     1     1
#2     1     2
#3     1     3
#4     2     1
#5     2     2
#6     2     3
```

Also there is `expand_grid` in `tidyr`

```
tidyr::expand_grid(x= 1:2, y = 1:3)
```